# Code generator for Android layout files from using Java Annotations

Tags: android, user-interface, reflection, annotations

Is there any library that could help in generating XML (layout) files in android. I have explored java poet but it is not helping in XML files.

Comment: What would you generate the layout files from?

Comment: something like this? https://code.google.com/archive/p/droiddraw/

Comment: @IvanWooll from Java Annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). It is a solid open source library supports many data formats, xml included.

The basic idea is create an Java model of xml files and then generate them with jackson library.